# trying to import database using sql command?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to import database using sql command?

```
mysql -u 'root' -p '' -h localhost learndb < 'C:\Users\owner\Downloads\my_app.sql'
```

root is my username.
I haven't set password.
learndb is my database name where I am importing the my_app database.
my_app.sql this file is located on C:\Users\owner\Downloads this path.

but this query is not working. is it correct? if not then what is the correct way?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a `-D` before database name?

Comment: That's not a SQL command. It's a mysql command.  What is the contents of the .sql file?

Comment: I am doing this first time.I clicked on export tab then the my_app.sql file is created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a blank password on the command line, you have to use the long form of the option:

```bash
mysql -u 'root' --password= -h localhost learndb < 'C:\Users\owner\Downloads\my_app.sql'
```

The short option doesn't allow a space between the option and the password, it has to be `-pPass`. But if there's no value there, it means that it should prompt for the password instead of getting it from the command line.

This command is intended to be typed directly in a Command Prompt window, not in the `mysql>` prompt. If you're in the `mysql` program already, you can do:

```
mysql> use learndb
mysql> source C:/Users/owner/Downloads/my_app.sql
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -u 'root' --password= -h localhost learndb &lt; 'C:\Users\owner\Downloads\my_' at line 1

Comment: You should be typing this command in the `Command Prompt` window, not at the `mysql>` prompt.

Comment: how can I connect to mysql using command Prompt? do you know that command?